# Rails select all children of children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, children

My class S has many class A who has many B.

I can get all A's for my S (S.As)
I can iterate over this array and get Bs for every A.

something like

```
S.As.each do |aa| 
    aa.Bs
end
```

How can I do the same without using 'each'?

Comment: Will this help you: `S.A.map(&:B)` which will return only `B` ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work in one line without `each`

```
S.As.collect(&:Bs)
```

Comment: I think that he want to get the output  without `each` which I have answer to.. @mark please if you can re read

Comment: Yes so you should rather suggest this to me rather than saying it is not an answer. Nevertheless I will update the answer. Had given quite answers. Never thought it would be down vote just for the statement.

Comment: Just note that `collect` used like this returns a nested array of arrays. Let's say `S.As.size == 6` and `S.As.each { |a| a.Bs.size }.sum == 20`. If you use collect as above you'll get `S.As.collect(&:Bs).size == 6` and you'll need to flatten: `S.As.collect(&:Bs).flatten.size == 20`

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is with N+1 Queries, I suggest using `includes`

Right now a new query is generated for each As to get it's Bs.

If you write it like this:

```
S.As.includes(:Bs).each do |aa| 
    aa.Bs
end
```

you will get way less queries, because all Bs will be preloaded.

map and collect won't change anything in this case.

Comment: I will pick another answer as a correct, cause it more precise answer to my question. But definitely will use your method, cause it should work faster. Thanks.

Comment: @ekiyanov it's a good method where there aren't too many records.